# OneNote online - Navigation options disabled

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I've been using Onenote and have a couple of notebooks synced across devices.

Onenote works fine on my local devices PC, tablet etc. However when using Chrome it opens a page and you cannot browse to any sections or pages. The navigation options are disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I opened onenote.com in incognito window and let it load.

It took a while but then the side bar appeared and the navigation options were enabled.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In two days you'll be able to accept your own answer to indicate that the problem is solved.